# Moment.js doesn't change locale

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I have `React Project` and I use `moment.js` for work with date. I tried to change language/locale with official documentation, nothing helped, here's my code:

```js
const moment = require('moment');

class Calendar extends Component {
  render() {
    const variable = moment();
    console.log(variable.locale('ru').format('dddd')) // Thursday
    console.log(moment.locale('ru')); // en
    return (
      <div className="calendar-container">
        Calendar
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Also I tried `import '../../node_modules/moment/src/locale/ru.js'`
 did't work either(Error: Cannot find module "./locale"). Any idea how fix this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try adding:

```
import 'moment/locale/ru';
```

and using:

```
moment.locale('ru');
```

To set the locale.

Comment: Importing the locale is the key. Then you can set it either globally or locally. Thanks man.

Comment: I have an error in Nextjs: "Warning: Text content did not match. Server: XXX Client:YYY"
import 'moment/locale/ru';  <--- Solved my problem!

Thank you.